# use library crossplatform: DWORD is unsigned int(Linux) unsigned long (Windows)

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, typedef

i wrote a small Qt application under Linux that accesses some hardware. To do that i have a 3rd party library from the vendor with simple c-funktions.

Under Linux the 3rd party header file defines a DWORD as unsigned int but when i compile the application with Qt Creator (MinGW compiler) on windows DWORD is defined as unsigned long and i get a lot of:

```
typedef redefinition with different types(unsigned int vs unsigned long)
```

Is there a clever way to deal with this to make my project run on both OS ?

Comment: `DWORD` has *always* been `unsigned long` on Windows. Ever since `int` was 16 bits, and `long` was 32.

Comment: @BoPersson: probably that library defines it as `unsigned int` (or possibly `uint32_t` which in turn may be defined as `unsigned int`) for compatibility with 64 bit Linux.

Comment: @Matteo - Sure. Being kind of Windows centric, I just felt a need to point out that Windows added these typedefs around 1985 and so cannot be blamed for other software using different definitions.  :-)

Comment: I know it is like this on Windows and i don't want to blame anybody for something. I am looking for a nice solution to deal with the problem.
the linux methods want unsigned int
the windows method wants unsigned long
and i dont want to write 2 kind of wrappers for them ;-)

Comment: nobody an Idea ?